# How to sniff another app's traffic in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, network-programming

I am using an app that sends information that I need as email, and I have to use it at first 30 seconds after it has been sent. So the only way I see for getting information on time is using program on the same computer, which is only possible if you use traffic sniffer(or maybe there is some other way?). So is there a way to listen all traffic that another app sends to the Internet in OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Wire shark should do the trick.
https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: I've tried it, but it did not launch on my Mac(said it needed X11 and when I installed it nothing changed)

Comment: It seems to be a known problem, check https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/36367/wireshark-doesnt-start-after-upgrading-to-mac-os-x-yosemite for a solution.